# Initialization of structure - C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I don't understand why this doesn't work:
I have the structure

```
typedef struct{
    float* charge;
    int length;
}Colas;
```

and I want to initialize an instance of "Colas" in main from another function "bucle":

```
//From "length", compute "charge":
Colas* bucle(int length){
    Colas* cola = malloc(sizeof(Colas));
    cola->length = length;
    float seed = 3.5;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<length; i=i+1){
        cola->charge[i] = seed/(i+1);
}
return cola;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int length = atoi(argv[1]);//Here I extract the value from argv
    Colas* cola;
    cola = bucle(length);
    printf("InMain: %f", cola->charge[0]);
}
```

The last print gives a number like "81239127637182637182", different from the correct value printed in "bucle".

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: what is `charge` in `bucle()`? Where do you declare it or etc

Comment: charge in the struct is a pointer to float, you need to set up a float variable for it to point to, or just declare the float variable

Comment: `cola->charge = charge;` -> `cola->charge = malloc(length * sizeof(float);` perhaps

Comment: I dont put the code where i declare and compute "charge" (in "bucle) because it is a long algorthm

Comment: show it please. Even if it is long.

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable. Which doesn't exist anymore after the function has returned.

Comment: `cola->charge = charge;` from where is this second `charge` coming from?

Comment: @melpomene I think you may be right. I updated the code, but it now doesnt even run :(

Comment: @melpomene.: Correct me if I am wrong - where do you see the `charge` variable? Is this code even compiling?

Comment: @coderredoc No, this is made up code (see e.g. the missing `;` at the end of `main`). I think the previous `carga` was meant to be `charge` (translation error?).

Comment: @melpomene.: Current edit deletes that line.

Comment: sorry for the mistakes, I am used to math.stack, where the comments are slower hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the code you edited, that is accessing some uninitialized value and tries to modify it - invoking undefined behavior.

```
cola->charge = malloc(length * sizeof * cola->charge);
```

Now you have allocated memory for `length` number of floating point variables. And assign the address of the allocated chunk to `cola->charge`.

If you notice carefully, here we have dynamically allocated memory which has lifetime beyond the scope of the function `bucle`. So you can access it provided you know the address of the chunk, which is what is being done here.

So the code will be something like

```
Colas* bucle(int length){
    Colas* cola = malloc(sizeof *cola);
    if( cola == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
        exit(1);
    }

    cola->length = length;
    cola->charge = malloc(cola->length * sizeof * cola->charge);
    if( cola->charge == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
        exit(1);    
    }
    float seed = 3.5;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        cola->charge[i] = seed/(i+1);
    }
    return cola;
}
```

Check the return value of `malloc`. In case it fails and returns `NULL` you won't run into error accessing it. Free the dynamically allocated memory after you are done working with it.(using `free()`).

---

Also `atoi` provides no error handling. It is better to use `strtol` etc. Those provide better error handling.

Comment: @sg7.: Thanks but they are not typos. If I remove those *` that would mean I want to allocate memory for `Colas*` but which is not the case (1st malloc). I want to get the type what is pointed by `cola` that is `Colas`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof *Colas);` will not compile as such. You need to allocate size of the structure.

Comment: @sg7.: The typo was the capital name but not the `*`s. We need to dereference the variable not the type.

Comment: All is good now, thank you! For length = 3; the result is `InMain: 3.500000 
InMain: 1.750000 
InMain: 1.166667` Part of my confusion was that I personally prefer to allocate directly size of the structure or type.

Comment: @sg7.: Yes that's also a way to do but it helps  this way because you know ..for large pointer types (2 or 3 *s) it is good because you don't need to count * to get the correct type. Also changing the type later is just having one place change. That's it

Comment: _Also changing the type later is just having one place change._ Good practical point! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of the program is with lack of allocation of the memory for the `charge`. You may also want to check if memory was allocated. If memory is not allocated the `malloc` will return `NULL.`

This is illustration of proper allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    float * charge;
    int length;
}Colas;

//From "length", compute "charge":
Colas* bucle(int length){
    //(compute charge)
    Colas* cola = malloc(sizeof(Colas));

    cola->charge = malloc(length * sizeof(float));

    cola->length = length; 

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        cola->charge[i] = (float)i;

        printf("InBucle: %f\n", cola->charge[i]);
    }

    return cola;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int length = 3;

    Colas* cola;
    cola = bucle(length);

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        printf("InMain: %f \n", cola->charge[i]);

    // remember to free memory
    free(cola->charge);
    free(cola);

 return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
InBucle: 0.000000
InBucle: 1.000000
InBucle: 2.000000
InMain: 0.000000 
InMain: 1.000000 
InMain: 2.000000
```